# Android Application Dashboard with pin/password to exit

Tags: android

Here I'm trying to implement an Android Application Dashboard where user press the exit button to be asked for a pin or a password to exit the application, or go to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can not control the behaviour of the Home key whenever it is pressed the home screen will be shown however you can bring your application in foreground as soon as Home screen is shown.
2. When exit button is pressed then you can ask user to enter the credentials. you can do this either in alert dialog with custom layout or taking user to other activity.
3. You can use SharedPreference to store the credentials if the data is limited else SQlite.

That's what you are asking ?

Comment: Presumably if one really wanted to, they could override what the 'Home' button does by modifying the Android source code itself, and building their own version of the OS?

Comment: hello, how can you implement your option number 1?